# Reinit owl-carousel after updating ng-repeat elements

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, owl-carousel

I'm using owl carousel with ng-repeat and I'm trying reinitiliaze the carousel when ng-repeat elements are updated.

I have the following html:

```
<div class="row">       
    <div owl-carousel class="new-carousel-holder">
        <div owl-carousel-item ng-repeat="c in categories" class="item">
            <a href="#" >
                <div class="img-holder">
                    <img ng-src="{{ c.image }}" alt="">
                    <span>{{ c.name | translate }}</span>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

These are the directives:

```
angular.module 'app'
.directive 'owlCarouselItem', () ->
    restrict: 'A'
    transclude: false
    link: (scope, element) ->

        initCarousel = () ->
            if scope.$last
                 scope.initCarousel element.parent()

        initCarousel()
```

and

```
angular.module "app"
.directive "owlCarousel", () ->
    restrict: "A"
    transclude: false
    link: (scope, elem, attr) ->

        scope.initCarousel = (element) ->
            $(element).owlCarousel
                stagePadding: 85
                loop: true
                margin: 22
                nav: true
                responsive:
                    0: items: 4
                    760: items: 7
                    1000: items: 10
                    1200: items: 13
```

The problem is that the categories model can change and I need to reinit the carousel. I tried different approaches but none of them worked for me.

Comment: are you solved this problem ? ... I have same.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this could help. I worked on [this directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35453492/how-to-create-a-lightbox-similar-to-facebook-using-owl-carousel-in-angularjs) to make it works with owl-carousel 2.0.0-beta-2.4

it waits for the last item in the ng-repeat then call the carousel init function with a timeout

here's a working [plunker](https://run.plnkr.co/plunks/pWAmBd/)